# Directly assigning numbers to char and a touch of arithmetic

Tags: c, char

We know that we can directly assign numbers as a char just like ch1 = 36.

36 is in hexadecimal, am I right?

And what if I do one or both of these:

```
ch1 = ch1 + 1

while(ch1 <78)
```

^is 1 in decimal or hexadecimal? Do I need to convert ch1 to be able to compare or change the value of ch1?

Comment: 36 is Decimal not hexadecimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to 'convert' between them, as the decimal , hexadecimal and ASCII values are all simply different ways of representing 8-bits of data.

36 is decimal. To write 36 in hexadecimal you'd use the literal 0x36, as in:

```
ch1 = 0x36
```